# EF Code First Migration unwanted column IdentityRole_Id

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 6.1.1
When i use code-first migration on my DB, it adds two unwanted columns to the AspNetUserRoles table: IdentityRole_Id, IdentityUser_Id
I've seen this [RemoveFromRole cannot work as expected](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/125), but didnt help me.

how do i get rid of them ??

this is my OnModelCreating

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }

        // Keep this:
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        // Change TUser to ApplicationUser everywhere else - 
        // IdentityUser and ApplicationUser essentially 'share' the AspNetUsers Table in the database:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

        // EF won't let us swap out IdentityUserRole for ApplicationUserRole here:            
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) =>
            new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        // Leave this alone:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey((IdentityUserLogin l) =>
                new
                {
                    UserId = l.UserId,
                    LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider,
                    ProviderKey
                        = l.ProviderKey
                }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        //entityTypeConfiguration.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserLogin u) => u.User);
        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        //table1.HasRequired<IdentityUser>((IdentityUserClaim u) => u.User);

        // Add this, so that IdentityRole can share a table with ApplicationRole:
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        // Change these from IdentityRole to ApplicationRole:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
    }
```

and it produces this:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    IdentityRole_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    IdentityUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.IdentityRole_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.IdentityUser_Id)
            .Index(t => t.IdentityRole_Id)
            .Index(t => t.IdentityUser_Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Identity EntityFramework (your DbcontextClass  : IdentityDbContext) then I think this line is the reason

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) =>
        new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
```

All the code in your OnModelCreating will create the same identity tables as default (as long as your application context class derives from  `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

If you want to use an override OnModelCreating for some reason for example

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
       modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
 }
```

then you have to call the base

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```